# Error in ridirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

i already have .htaccess file in root directory with this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ list.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Now, i also want to ridirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS pages using this htaccess file without removing existing codes, i tried some codes but i see error by browsers such as "Not Ridirecting Properly".
plz tell me some code according to the existing .htaccess file. 
Thanks A Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do it with .htaccess, do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

You can also do it easily with a separate VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourname.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName yourname.example.com
```